# Short story from the point of view of a small animal being eaten?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror, animals

From my childhood I remember a weird short story (?) written from the point of view of a small animal. The only thing I can really remember of the plot is that it contained a very disturbing (to me) description of what it was like to be eaten by another animal. Perhaps another(?) snail, mollusk or insect. This would have been written in the '70s or earlier.

There is a Patricia Highsmith story from 1967 called "The Quest for Blank Claveringi" about a *scientist* eaten by giant snails. I read it online just before posting this, and I don't think it is the story I remember. None of it seemed familiar (except for the eating part).

Can anyone recall a similar story written from an animal's viewpoint?

Comment: where did you read online "the quest for blank claveringi" ? I am trying to find it but am unable.

Comment: @nestedloop: For you, or others searching, the Internet Archive currently has three books available for checkout [here](https://archive.org/search.php?query=%22The%20Quest%20for%20Blank%20Claveringi%22) that contain the story.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Wow, you revived an oldie, you should get some badge :)) Thanks, will look into that!

Answer (score 3):

Could it be [*Archy and Mehitabel*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archy_and_Mehitabel)? It's a collection of musings, essays, and poems by a cockroach, and it certainly qualifies as "weird." One entry is "The Robin and the Worm," a poem from the perspective of a worm being eaten by a bird.

Comment: "The Robin and the Worm." Thanks for mentioning it. I looked it up and read it, but unfortunately it's not what I was thinking of.